# Binding .Bind(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, nameof(BackArrowTapped)); to a grid doesn't call my BackArrowTapped command

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
public ScrollHeadingView2()
{
   outerGrid = new Grid() { BackgroundColor = Color.Red, RowSpacing = 0, ColumnSpacing = 0 };
   outerGrid.AddChild(new BoxView() 
   { 
      HeightRequest = 100, 
      WidthRequest = 100, 
      BackgroundColor = Color.Pink 
   }, 0, 0);
   var tap1 = new TapGestureRecognizer() 
   { 
      NumberOfTapsRequired = 1 
   }.Bind(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, nameof(BackArrowTapped));
   grid1.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap1);
}

private async Task BackArrowTapped()
{
    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync(false);
}
```

The pink area of the grid displays but when I place a break on the await then it doesn't go there when I tap that area.

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: `BackArrowTapped` is not a command.  If you want to use an event handler, just set the gesture's Tapped property

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I could do this just for the grid1. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BackArrowTapped` is not a command. If you want to use an event handler, just set the gesture's Tapped property

```
tap1.Tapped += async (s,o) => { await BackArrowTapped(); };
```